# How to perform crud operation through linq on database in multiple transaction?

Tags: c#, linq

I never used it before, now i have need to perform crud operation through inq to database

I have 3 collection that i want to push in 3 different tables in the database.

All three collections belong to a interface to show something there

I want to know how the update and add new operation should be performed. like in simele sqlcommand like statement i was using single save method that had the update stored procedure and check it whether to add a new new item or it is in edit so if a new entry is made the first table returns it primary that i assign to other collection one of proerty and push it the same way.

My concern is how to do the same here that if a new entry is pushed to database the primary key should b returned that i can map to other collection's property?

Comment: you mention linq (well, "inq") - are you using an ORM here? if so, which? Entity Framework? LINQ-to-SQL? the answer depends on this

Comment: My file extention is .dbml. where i query and get tables and want to push in to same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, you are using LINQ-to-SQL; in which case, the ORM deals with this *for you*. For example:

```
var cust = new Customer();
ctx.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(cust);
cust.Orders.Add(new Order { Quantity = 1, Part = "abc" } );
cust.Orders.Add(new Order { Quantity = 1, Part = "def" });
ctx.SubmitChanges();
```

when you call `SubmitChanges`, the ORM will handle:

- performing the necessary inserts and updates
- updating any necessary metadata (identity, rowversion, etc) on any objects
- etc

so - after the call to `SubmitChanges`, you should see that `cust` has picked up whatever identity it is meant to have. In particular, note that when adding `Order` etc, I added *objects*, not identities. This is necessary because we don't *know* the identity yet. Note also that this uses a *single* transaction.